# How to invoke custom function within g:if test="..." without providing it (or object instance) to the model?

Tags: grails

**The background is**:

1. I have layout page main.gsp
2. I need to conditionally show or hide menu item
3. Condition evaluation is done by querying database
4. I don't want to augment each controller so it will evaluate this condition and put result to the model

**The issue is**:
I'm trying to do something like that

```
<g:if test="${checkCondition()}"> some html here </g:if>
```

But it fails saying that checkCondition in undefined.

But this works perfectly:

```
<mytaglib:checkCondition />
```

**The question is**:
What should I do to be able to call my function within

```
<g:if test="${ expression }">
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have the tag in a namespace ('mytaglib') you need to call it as a method with that namespace too:

```
<g:if test="${mytaglib.checkCondition()}"> some html here </g:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

move the checkCondition() as a static method into a class and import this class in your gsp. you can also define a service class with this method and directly call this serivce method from your gsp. the **clearest solution** is to define, as you described, your own taglib. within your tag lib you can inject service beans with helper methods and so on.

in your taglib you can do something like

```
def checkCondition = { attrs ->
   // place your condition here
   if (session.user.id = 1) {
       // show menu
       out << "menu"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried to define service class and call it's method. But it says that it wants this method to be static in order to call it. But if I'll make it static - DI won't work. What should I do to be able to call service method?